# Why is ajax result not shown in the child view?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I’m doing an ajax call like this:

```
 @Ajax.ActionLink("My Schedule", "GetSchedule", "Schedule", new { selectedDate = strToday}, new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "theTimes", InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace, HttpMethod = "GET" })
```

It calls a partial view that has a datapicker on it.  Here’s what the controller action looks like:

```
   public ActionResult GetSchedule(string selectedDate)
    {

        ViewBag.fromGetSchedule = selectedDate; 
        var viewModel = new ScheduleData();


        String dayofweek = DateTime.Now.DayOfWeek.ToString();
    viewModel.Courses = db.Courses;

    int intTeacherId = Convert.ToInt32(Session["intTeacherId"]);

        DateTime daySearch = Convert.ToDateTime(selectedDate);
        viewModel.Assignments = from a in db.Assignments where a.teacherId == intTeacherId select a;





    viewModel.Assignments = (from x in db.Assignments where x.teacherId == intTeacherId && x.Date == daySearch select x).ToList();



    ViewBag.theDate = daySearch.ToShortDateString();



        return PartialView(viewModel);

    }

}
```

This all works fine.  It calls the partial view that looks like this:

```
 @model SchoolIn.ViewModels.ScheduleData

  @{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
    }


 <link href="../../Content/themes/base/jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom.css" rel="stylesheet"
type="text/css" />

  <link href="../../Content/themes/base/jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
type="text/css" />

  <script src="../../Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
   <script src="../../Scripts/jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

   <script src="../../Scripts/jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

  <div class ="ui-widget" >
  <label for ="datep">Date: </label><input id="datep" />



  </div>
  @ViewBag.theDate

  @if (Model.Assignments != null)
  {

   <table>
     <tr>
   <th>
      Assignment  Course
    </th>



    <th>
        Class Day
    </th>


    <th>
     Class Time
    </th>


</tr>

@foreach (var item in Model.Assignments.Select((x, i) => new { Data = x, Index = i }))
  {


<tr>
<td>

    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Data.Course)

</td>


    <td>





         @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Data.HomeworkGrade)

    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Data.Date)
    </td>




</tr>
}


 </table>

 }


<input type="hidden" autofocus=true/>




  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
    $("#datep").datepicker({ showOn: "both", buttonText: "Select Date", changeMonth: true, changeYear: true, yearRange: "-2:+2", showOtherMonths: true, onSelect: function (date, datepickder) {
        var sltdDate = { selectedDate: date };
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "/Schedule/GetSchedule",
            data: sltdDate,
            datatype: "html",
            sucess: function (data) {

            }
        });

    }




        });

      });
  </script>
```

Then on the partial view I select a date from the datepicker and an ajax call is made to the same action as I mentioned earlier.  Again linq query goes well and all is fine.  I check the code in the view to see if it’s receiving the data sent from the controller using break points and the data does come through but it does not display in the view.  It shows the table’s heading but nothing in the @Html.Foreach(){} loop.

Why is ajax result not shown in the child view?  Thanks again for any help with this one.

Comment: should you be doing something with the data returned in the success handler of the ajax request?

Comment: I haven't in other times I've used ajax request...not sure if it's a necessity.

Answer (score 0):

First I needed to correct the typo... sucess to success then I wrapped the view in a div container then put returned data in the div container with the success function. Here's what the success function looks like.

```
  success: function (data) {
                $("#returnedData").html(data);

            }
```